# how to get Online QBO item sku using item id in php sdk

Tags: quickbooks, product, sku

I am using this code of consolibyte to getting sku of QuickBooks online products but there is no response?

```
<?php
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/config.php';
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/views/header.tpl.php';

$ItemService = new QuickBooks_IPP_Service_Term();

$items = $ItemService->query($Context, $realm, "SELECT * FROM Item WHERE id = '4' ");   

foreach ($items as $item)
{
            print_r($item->getSku()); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use my custom made SDK. I had to add a GET parameter "minorversion" = 4 to include Sku in both requests and responses.